# looking for simple example to how to load local images inside ListView with AsyncTask?

Tags: android, multithreading, image, listview, android-asynctask

i found some examples but they show how to loading images from url .

i saw this in

http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html

// Using an AsyncTask to load the slow images in a background thread

```
new AsyncTask<ViewHolder, Void, Bitmap>() {
    private ViewHolder v;

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(ViewHolder... params) {
        v = params[0];
        return mFakeImageLoader.getImage();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if (v.position == position) {
            // If this item hasn't been recycled already, hide the
            // progress and set and show the image
            v.progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            v.icon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            v.icon.setImageBitmap(result);
        }
    }
}.execute(holder);
```

my code

```
viewHolder.ivLogo.setImageResource(LogoId);
```

i want to put this simple line into AsyncTask .

thanks .

Answer (score 0):

http://android-developers.blogspot.pt/2010/07/multithreading-for-performance.html

Look at this it will help you a lot baby